# How similar is the WLLN to "converges in probability"?

Tags: convergence, law-of-large-numbers

How similar is the weak law of large numbers to convergence in probability?

It seems that one can use WLLN to display convergence in probability. Like displayed here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakLawofLargeNumbers.html

Answer (score 3):

Similar is not really the right word.  The Weak Law of Large Numbers states that under specified conditions, the sample mean converges in probability to the mean.  Using a more refined proof, the Weak Law of large Numbers holds for independent and identically distributed random variables which have a finite mean.  The assumption of finite standard deviation included in the Math World statement is unnecessary, but its exclusion makes the proof more difficult.

Note that convergence in probability can also apply to things other than weak law of large numbers.